# Passing clicked hyperlink text in query string

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, crystal-reports-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition.

I have a Crystal Report on which one column contains hyperlink values coming from a stored procedure. When the user clicks on any of these hyperlink values, a next page [here, ReportAllBlocks.aspx] should open but I want to pass this value as a query string.

For example: The user clicked on a hyperlink text: `New York`, so the URL should become:

```
http://localhost:1031/myProject/ReportAllBlocks.aspx?New York
```

I am not following how to add this hyperlink value to the URL, either in the box shown below, or programatically through C#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a formula field.  First create a parameter for the url(or hard code the value if it never changes).
In the formula editor:

```
{?URLParameter} + {Table.Field}
```

Then add the formula to your report, open the format editor, and select 'Current Website Field Value' instead of 'A File'.  The field will now become a hyperlink.  It will still look like text just act different when clicked so you may want to change the font color and underline.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Justin. It works even if I only give something like: "ReportAllBlocks.aspx?"+{?URL Parameter}.